# How can I change to a new page when resized to mobile in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I’m trying to move to another page that has a coming soon page when resized on mobile. Does anyone know how I could do this in react.js?

Comment: Do you want to display a "coming soon"-page, if the user opens your site on a mobile device?

Comment: You can check the window.innerWidth, then if the innerWidth is less than XXX(maybe 400?) you can push the user to your coming soon page.

Comment: Hey guys, yes I’m trying to make a it so when you move to mobile the page switch into a “coming soon” page.

Comment: Okay, thanks @shai_sharakanski I'll look into that.